# Why DistinctBy does not contain a definition?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a table of product specifications I do not want duplicate elements to be displayed when displaying product specifications. I did this, but the error is displayed. Where did I go wrong?

And displays this error:
'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition

```
 private static List<ProductPropertiesQueryModel> 
  MapProductProperties(List<ProductProperties> ProductProperties)
    {
       return ProductProperties
        .Select(x=>new ProductPropertiesQueryModel
        {
           ProductId =x.ProductId,
           Color =x.Color,
           Size=x.Size
        }).DistinctBy(r=>r.Color).ToList();                      
    }
```

Comment: Did you try move ```Distinc``` before  ```Select``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DistinctBy` [came with .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-6) (**New LINQ APIs** section). Looks like you are using lower version. You can try one of these below.

**1- You can write extension on your own,**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> listItems, Func<T, TKey> groupingKey)
{
     return listItems.GroupBy(groupingKey).Select(x => x.First());
}
```

**2- Upgrade your .NET version,**

**3- Use `GroupBy()` directly,**

```
private static List<ProductPropertiesQueryModel> MapProductProperties(List<ProductProperties> ProductProperties)
{
       return ProductProperties
        .Select(x=>new ProductPropertiesQueryModel
        {
           ProductId =x.ProductId,
           Color =x.Color,
           Size=x.Size
        }).GroupBy(x => x.Color).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();                 
}
```

**4- Use [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) to have `DistinctBy()`**